# How to display the your GitHub timeline / feeds on your website

Tags: java, github

How The steps to get your GitHub feeds/ TimeLine and display them in your website

In GitHub we could see our recent activities. how to get them displayed on our website if required?

Comment: easy, but first, do you have access to a computer, the internet, google, and a small cocktail umbrella?

Comment: Did you just post a (bad) question as an excuse to publish a readymade answer you had? Well... whatever makes you happy, I guess :)

Comment: Please check the tags: you tagged the question with "javascript", but then the answer includes java

Answer (score 1):

This document explains how to display your GitHub feeds/timeline on your website.

Note: [it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

**Example:** A live example is available at:

> https://newtonjoshua.com

**GitHub timeline:**

GitHub provides the public timeline for any user in Atom format.

You can view your timeline at:

> https://github.com/{{GitHub_username}}.atom

refer:
https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/feeds

**Reading the Feeds**

The below is a Java code to parse the atom feeds.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONException;
import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.XML;

public class Feeds {
    public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;

    public static JSONObject getFeeds(String inputUrl) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(inputUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        String line, outputString = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            outputString += line;
        }

        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = null;

        try {
            xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(outputString);
            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
        return xmlJSONObj;  
    }
}
```

Using the above feed parses, read the atom feed and then you can format and display your GitHub feeds/timeline on your website.

Comment: what are your trying to do ?

Comment: @brk: I GitHub we could see our recent activities. This is to get them displayed on our website if required